# Providing a Solution - Best Contract Form?

Tags: contracts

Our company, a small team, may be providing a software solution to a larger client. The solution, a website, resides entirely on our servers and is branded for our customer. We have total ownership of the software and hardware. In effect, the solution will look and feel to an End User as if they are interacting with our client.

Our solution does a little processing of data from the End User and passes the results on to the client. We have no further involvement and there is no money flow from the client to us, our revenue is purely from the End User interacting with our site.

**Question**: What is the most suitable contract to enter into for this form of work? We are not developing, nor are we maintaining. Our best guess is a Saas, but the client never owns the solution.

Comment: "We have total ownership of the software and hardware" sounds exactly like developing and maintaining? I'm also wondering if this question isn't more suitable for the software stackexchange...

Comment: Yes, but we never hand it over. We retain ownership. So its a partnership. Unlike being asked to develop a solution and at the end of the cycle, hand over the goods to walk away or maintain.

Comment: I think this is more a question for an attorney.

Answer (score 2):

You said SaaS, you're spot on. You host it, maintain it, support it. The client pays for it to just work. This is Software As A Service.